# How to get the magic hestia knife?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

I have exchanged the p.attack hestia knife. Can I still get the magic hestia knife by any means?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can by clearing bell episode 29 on very hard difficulty.

Comment: The answer system is dedicated to giving an actual answer to a question. This is not really the place to post comments like these.